# Independent logins for different client application ( identityserver4 | angular-oauth-oidc)

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, openid, angular-oauth2-oidc

We have multiple clients using `response_type:code` (Authorization Code Flow with PKCE) to communicate with identity server 4 to log users in.

The clients are in `angular` framework and uses `angular-oauth-oidc` library and uses `localstorage` as storage.

Right now when the user logs in on client 1, and opens client 2 in the same browser, he/she is logged in automatically(or at least there is some interference during login/endsession). This is not desirable behaviour in our case. We want all 3 of our client apps(with 3 client ids) to behave completely independent.

Is there a configuration that I can set in the client side or our `identityserver4` backend to make the users login independently on all three clients?

Option 1: To use session storage instead of localstorage in clients. This is not desirable either because we want users to be able to stay logged in even after closing the window.

Option 2: setting prompt=login seems to do the trick but not sure if this is the right approach. Any insights on this?

Is there a standard/correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you not give each client its own origin (domain) as a way to keep them separate? like client1.company.com client2.company.com?

Comment: OIDC (OAuth) is a Single Sign On protocol - that is intended behaviour. So don't use SSO protocol. Eventually, you can use `Password Grant Type`, so SSO session won't be created.

Answer (score 0):

On the front-end side, you can solve only *parts* of this challenge. As you indicated, you'll need to make sure each instance of your app is either completely isolated, or at least implement a custom `AuthStorage` that for example prefixes all keys with the client_id, e.g.:

```typescript
export class ClientBasedOAuthStorage implements OAuthStorage {
  private scope: string = "default";

  constructor() {
    this.scope = environment.oauthOptions.scope; // or some such
  }
  
  getItem(key: string): string {
    return localStorage.getItem(`${this.scope}_${key}`);
  }
  
  removeItem(key: string): void {
    localStorage.removeItem(`${this.scope}_${key}`);
  }

  setItem(key:string, data: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem(`${this.scope}_${key}`, data);
  }
}
```

If you use `sessionStorage` or some other isolated storage you're already good to go.

Now, on the server side, I presume most things will "just work". All requests made to the IdentityServer4 instance will be provided with a `client_id` and should then already be correctly scoped. The only thing that might give you trouble is the "remember me" cookie for IDS4, but the csharp side of things has plenty of interception points you can inject as well to control that behavior.